# Unit Testing the root component of the React Web Application

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-dom

How to test the root component which is rendered through react-dom render function?

I am working on this react component.

```
 export default class EWAWeb extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Provider store={store} >
                <Router>
                    <Switch>
                        <Route exact path="/" component={SplashScreen} />
                        <Route path="/start" component={SplashScreen} />
                        <Route path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
                    </Switch>
                </Router>
            </Provider>
        );
    }
}

render(<EWAWeb />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Inside JEST

```
describe('To test the Login Component functionality.', () => {
    configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });
    let compEWAWebParent = null;

    it(`should mount and check.`, () => {
            compEWAWebParent = mount(<EWAWeb />);
            const isReduxProvider = compEWAWebParent.find(Provider);
            expect(isReduxProvider).toHaveLength(1);
        });
});
```

I am writing this simple test to check.
If I remove the below line, test is working well,

```
render(<EWAWeb />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

otherwise throwing error:

> Invariant Violation: Target container is not a DOM element.

I don't want to segregate the files and also don't want to use document .body.

Thank you.

The issue is resolved and I have achieved 100% code coverage.

Thank you.

**Solution**

```
export default class EWAWeb extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Provider store={store} >
                <Router>
                    <Switch>
                        <Route exact path="/" component={SplashScreen} />
                        <Route path="/start" component={SplashScreen} />
                        <Route path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
                    </Switch>
                </Router>
            </Provider>
        );
    }
}

const containerDiv = document.getElementById('app');
render(<EWAWeb />, containerDiv || document.createElement('DIV'));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a couple of simple approaches here for you to consider:

1. Put the `Router` component and its children into their own component, which you can unit test easily and thoroughly, while not unit testing the resulting hollowed-out `EWAWeb` component at all. (Automated acceptance tests would cover checking the basic React wiring-up that the `EWAWeb` component represents.)
2. Only call `render` when `document.getElementById` returns a valid object, so that you don't get an error when unit testing:

`const appElement = document.getElementById('app');
appElement && render(<EWAWeb />, appElement);`